# Query URL in Watson Assistant

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I'm working with Watson Assistant (V2). I'm configuring WA itself through the IBM front-end interface they offer, and use NodeJS to deploy it to their cloud.

I want to do the following:

1. User visits www.mysite.com/?productID=123 which contains the chatbot
2. The bot, upon launch, queries the URL and recognizes the productID.
3. The recognized productID is placed in my entity @productID so I can then use it as context variable $productID (or @productID.literal).

So far I haven't been able to find a way to put the productID in the @entity. I grab the productID by calling an onload function using a regex, and can display the productID in the chatbox. However what I cannot figure out is a way to somehow store this in the @entity.

I'm familiar with html/css/json/js, but not yet with the API that Watson offers.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the V2 API for IBM Watson Assistant, then you use [message](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2#send-user-input-to-assistant) to send user input to the chatbot engine. The request body has a context element with system and skill-related section. You can augment it and set app-related context variables. Use it to pass in your **productID**. There is no need to try to set it as entity.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand the process better now, but I'm still unable to access that variable. I've updated the request body to include a 'username' : 'Piet', and then try to show the username 'Piet' by putting $username in a dialog text field. Is there something I'm missing here? You can see what I did around line 70: https://pastebin.com/bnij3KVZ (tried both $username and $(username) as I see both being used in examples)

Comment: I have solved the issue, allowing your solution to work. It was a stupid mistake on my side. I was editting the context in app.js, assuming that a refresh of my localhost would suffice to retrigger calling the script (as with most other .js files used in nodejs Watson). However, app.js is obviously called on start of the service and only once, so I had to restart the entire service. Thanks for your help!